# cannot get ~/.bash_profile

Tags: bash, terminal

I am attempting to set up vs code on my work computer. When I run

```
~/.bash_profile
```

I get no such directory.

the ~/.   works fine.

I am seeing an issue with bash_profile.  Not sure how to fix it.  I tried a couple of other pasts on stack overflow I found, but at this point do not want to do that anymore as I do not know fully know what is happening

```
/.bash_profile "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

I can set up vs code in my terminal without it, but the changes that I make will not save and vs code will not open  **code .** .  When I work from a new terminal.

Comment: You can't open a file just by typing its name. Try `nano ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: If you don't have a `.bash_profile`, you need to create it. There might also be `.profile`, this is the generic name of the startup script.

Comment: `.bash_profile` isn't a program you run with arguments. It's a shell startup script that's run automatically when you login. You edit it to change what happens when you login, for instance to initialize environment variables needed by programs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `.bash_profile` is not a directory or a program, but rather a hidden file that is executed by the command interpreter for login shells.

Assuming you are using Mac OS X, you can place the following line in your `.bash_profile` file:

```
function code () { VSCODE_CWD="$PWD" open -n -b "com.microsoft.VSCode" --args $*; }
```

If the file does not exist, you can simply create it, open the file and add the line above as follows:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile
nano ~/.bash_profile
# paste the line above
# press Ctrl-X to exit, press 'Y' for yes, and Enter to save.
```

If you want to do the above in one line, simply do:

```
echo "function code () { VSCODE_CWD=\"$PWD\" open -n -b \"com.microsoft.VSCode\" --args $*; }" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Using `>>` ensures that contents in `.bash_profile` don't get destroyed during redirection if file exists. If file does not exist, a new file will be created.

Then restart your terminal, or type `source ~/.bash_profile`, and you should be able to run VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation